# Fixing running error of array in my java parser, also trying to fix the output print

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, input, trigonometry

This is a parser that go through 5 text documents of html sources. The parser will then go through each text file, count frequency of 5 keywords, then display the cosine similiarty.

1) There is Arrays cannot be resolved error around my arraylist line in parser.java

2) 
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;

```
public class DocumentParser {

    private void doSomething(){
            String text = "Professor, engineering, data, mining, research";
            StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(text);
            String word[] = new String[10];
            String unique[] = new String[10];
            String x;
            int count = -1;
            while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                count++;
                x = str.nextToken();
                word[count] = x;
               System.out.println(count + ": " + word[count]);
            }

            System.out.println("---Frequency---");
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

                if ((!Arrays.asList(unique).contains(word[i]))) {
                    unique[i] = word[i];
                }
            }

            int[] measure = new int[10];

            for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
                if (Arrays.asList(unique).contains(word[a])) {
                    measure[a] += 1;
                    System.out.println(unique[a] + " : " + measure[a]);
                }
            }
        }

    private List<String[]> termsDocsArray = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    private List<String> allTerms = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    private List<double[]> tfidfDocsVector = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    public void parseFiles(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File[] allfiles = new File(filePath).listFiles();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        for (File f : allfiles) {
            if (f.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String s = null;
                while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(s);
                }
                String[] tokenizedTerms = sb.toString().replaceAll("[\\W&&[^\\s]]", "").split("\\W+");   //to get individual terms
                for (String term : tokenizedTerms) {
                    if (!allTerms.contains(term)) {  
                        allTerms.add(term);
                    }
                }
                termsDocsArray.add(tokenizedTerms);
            }
        }

    }

    public void tfIdfCalculator() {
        double tf; 
        double idf; 
        double tfidf;       
        for (String[] docTermsArray : termsDocsArray) {
            double[] tfidfvectors = new double[allTerms.size()];
            int count = 0;
            for (String terms : allTerms) {
                tf = new TfIdf().getTf(docTermsArray, terms);
                idf = new TfIdf().idfCalculation(termsDocsArray, terms);
                tfidf = tf * idf;
                tfidfvectors[count] = tfidf;
                count++;
            }
            tfidfDocsVector.add(tfidfvectors);      
        }
    }
    public void getCosineMatrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tfidfDocsVector.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tfidfDocsVector.size(); j++) {
                System.out.println("between " + i + " and " + j + "  =  "
                                   + new CosineSimilarity().getCosine
                                       (
                                         tfidfDocsVector.get(i), 
                                         tfidfDocsVector.get(j)
                                       )
                                  );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like job proposal )

Comment: Spend this hour on reading book about java. No one will do your job instead of you.

Comment: As you print the cosin matrix score it is probably better to name the method accordingly. I'd expect it to return a value rather than printing something to the console. Next, your regex seems to be off. `[\\W&&[^\\s]]` does not make much sense to me. You create a character set that matches any none word character (note that certain character which may occur in words like è or é are also affected by this) or `&` characters (the 2nd one is redundant) or none whitespace characters where the inner character set won't be taken in my tests but can be replaced by `\\S` though will now match any

Comment: character that is a none word, or a none whitespace or a `&` character and therefore remove almost anything. Did you eventually mean something like `[\\W\\s]+`? This will remove all none word or whitespace characters and leave only the words and numbers within the text, though certain special word characters are removed again. In addition to that I'd replace unwanted characters with `" "` rather then `""` so you can split later on on none word characters

Comment: ad your compilation issue: remove the closing brace after the possible exceptions in the line: public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException`)` {

Answer (score 0):

This code block:

```
for(String file : files) {
    DocumentParser dp = new DocumentParser();
    dp.parseFiles(file);
    dp.getCosineMatrix();
}
```

Is not within a method, but should be.

Try moving it inside the `main()` method.

```
public class TfIdfMain {

    String[] files = {"doc1.txt", "doc2.txt", "doc3.txt" , "doc4.txt", "doc5.txt"};

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException) {
        for(String file : files) {
            DocumentParser dp = new DocumentParser();
            dp.parseFiles(file);
            dp.getCosineMatrix();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I cleaned up other problems with your code.

You should probably just do this at the top of your parser class:

```
import java.util.*;
```

as you haven't imported that, which is giving you the actual error,

Formatting your code in your IDE would really have helped you understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: @steve No, I won't email you directly. Post another question if you have another problem and can't find an answer to it after searching on this site.

Comment: thank you! but I have new error now. What I meant was it will be easier to post error, this is what I have now

Comment: The nested type TfIdfMain cannot hide an enclosing type

Comment: will you be on here for a while? Since I can't post another question for an hour, but I think reedit my question to show the latest error?

Comment: hey sir I updated my question with new error around the same main class, can you please take a look? thank you

Comment: I assume `TfIdfMain` is not in its own file; put it in one.

Comment: sir I just posed the new tfidmain class and my new error, can you please take a look?

Comment: mr are you there? I have two other classes, but it's too to post it on here.

Comment: @steve I've rolled back your destructive edits. which changed the nature of the question such that the answers given were not/less relevant. Please do not modify a question to ask another; post a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) There is Arrays cannot be resolved error around my arraylist line
>   in parser.java

You should import Arrays class like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

> 2) an error like this Multiple markers at this line in my main class

To be honest it's a mess here in your code. Where did you take it? Probably it should be:

```
String[] files = {"doc1.txt", "doc2.txt", "doc3.txt", "doc4.txt", "doc5.txt"};

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    DocumentParser dp = new DocumentParser();
    dp.parseFiles("C:\\Users\\dachen\\Documents");
    dp.getCosineMatrix();

    for (String file : files) {
        DocumentParser dp = new DocumentParser();
        dp.parseFiles(file);
        dp.getCosineMatrix();
    }

}
```